# Converting char into an int not working

Tags: c

I know there are multiple ways about this, but I am trying to get the user to input a character and have that character converted into a specific integer for later use. I am using `#define` constants to simplify things, in case something needs changing later on.
The value that I am getting for userChoice is not 0, 1,or 2 but a large number, so something is wrong.

These are the relevant parts of the code.

```
    #define ROCK 0
    #define PAPER 1
    #define SCISSORS 2
    void getData (int* userChoice)
{
    char charvalue;
    printf("\n\nEnter the R, P, S, or Q (for quit) ");
    scanf("%c", &charvalue);
    charvalue = toupper(charvalue);
    if (charvalue == 'R')
        *userChoice = ROCK;
    else if (charvalue == 'P')
        *userChoice = PAPER;
    else if (charvalue == 'S')
        *userChoice = SCISSORS;
    else if (charvalue == 'Q')
        exit (1);
    else
        printf("\nerror");
    printf("%d", userChoice);

    return;

}
```

Comment: `userChoice` is a pointer to an integer, not an integer as you are assuming in your `printf()`. Do you have compiler warnings turned on, or are you ignoring them? You should have received: `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print the *address* of your integer, not the value. To print the value, **use `*userChoice`**.

```
printf("%d", *userChoice);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Thought I do not quite understand why that is because in the past when I had a print function I did not need to use pointers to print the values.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a pointer to an int, so you must print the value of the pointer *userChoice.

A better practice would be to have the function return the choice as an unsigned int, instead of passing a reference and modifying the reference. In other words, it would be better to use an interface such as:

unsigned int getUserChoice(){ ... etc.